# Calling Twapi in 64 bit failure in 'freewraped' version

Tags: tcl, 64-bit

I have a strange problem in a current TCL program. It requires two libs, the muPDF and twapi. It has to be in 64 bit version due to muPDF being only available in 64bit. For the twapi it should be no problem, because it comes in both flavours in the first place. (the muPDF ist v 2.1.1, twapi is v 4.7.2)

So, assuming the following code:

```
    package require tclMuPDF
    package require twapi
```

everything runs fine under wish.exe in 64bit version.
Now I wrap this to an exe with freewrap675, using the 64bit version and then the strange thing happens:
The package req tclMuPDF goes without a problem. But the package req of twapi did not give me a lib, that is not found, but the error message

```
     invalid command name "twapi::get_build_config"
```

exactly at the point, the package req twapi is issued.

The strange thing is, that 'get_build_config' is a valid function of twapi, making it seem to be 'sort of loaded'.

I do not call 'get_build_config' anyway and as stated above, the error is thrown directly when calling 'package req twapi'.

What is going on? Can anybody give a hint? That would be really appreciated.

Comment: I'm guessing that the script that handles actually loading the package (set up by a `package ifneeded` call in the relevant `pkgIndex.tcl` file) calls that command. The `errorInfo` trace should say more. I've not found that command in [the source code](https://sourceforge.net/p/twapi/code/ci/default/tree/) but that might just be because I've not looked in the right place.

Comment: Also, try contacting the author of twapi to see if they can help.

Comment: @Donal: We always have these kind of problems, when it comes to creating EXEs. Our last findings was, that we often fall over a mechanism, that it seems, TCL uses a 'hidden' PATH, and that, this one comes right in front of auto_path always. I don't know, if this assumtion is right, but the results at least look like that. 
So, we're desperate enough to leave Freewrap behind and experiment with virtual images like "Enigma virtual Box", to get rid of all that hassle. 

Again, thanks for your kind and always insightful comments to any TCL related question here. It did and does help a lot!